# IF on WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

Hi how can I make this query work. I want a condition on where clause, that if @BACHNUMB = '',
then WHERE is (h.sopnumbe = @SOPNUMBE) Else WHERE is (h.bachnumb = @BACHNUMB). Thanks in advance.

```
WHERE
CASE(@BACHNUMB)
WHEN '' THEN (h.sopnumbe = @SOPNUMBE)
ELSE
(h.bachnumb = @BACHNUMB)
END
```

Comment: Re-tagged MySQL as you seem to be using MySQL-specific syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Simply recreate the logic through different syntax:

```
WHERE
(@BACHNUMB = '' AND h.sopnumbe = @SOPNUMBE) 
OR
(@BACHNUMB != '' AND h.bachnumb = @BACHNUMB)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

`(@BACHNUMB = '' and h.sopnumbe = @SOPNUMBE) or (@BACHNUMB != ' and 'h.bachnumb = @BACHNUMB)`

Comment: Note that this is slightly logically different - it's possible that `@BACHNUMB = ''` but the second half of the `OR` is true, thus the whole thing is true without regard to the value of `h.sopnumbe`.